# Using Canvas to animate a sorting algorithm in JS

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, sorting, canvas

For fun I am trying to create a visualization of different sorting algorithms, but I've run into an issue with Canvas animations.

I assumed I would just be able to call a draw function within the sorter method, but this causes the browser to lock up until the array is fully sorted and then draws some middle frame.

How would I go about animating from within the sorting methods? Below is the code I have so far, I wouldn't run this snippet as it will hang the tab for a few seconds.

```js
N = 250; // Array Size
XYs = 5; // Element Visual Size
Xp = 1; // Start Pos X
Yp = 1; // Start Pos Y
var canvas;
var l = Array.apply(null, {
  length: N
}).map(Number.call, Number);

Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
  var i = this.length,
    j, temp;
  if (i == 0) return this;
  while (--i) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    temp = this[i];
    this[i] = this[j];
    this[j] = temp;
  }
  return this;
}

function map_range(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) {
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}

function rainbow(x) {
  var m = map_range(x, 0, N, 0, 359);
  return 'hsl(' + m + ',100%,50%)';
}

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  l.shuffle();
  draw();
  bubbleSort(l);
}

function draw() {
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = rainbow(l[i]);
      ctx.fillRect((Xp * i) * XYs, Yp * XYs, XYs, XYs);
    }
  }
}

function bubbleSort(a) {
  var swapped;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
      if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
        var temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i + 1];
        a[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
        draw();
        setTimeout(function() {}, 10);
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body onload="init();">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1500" height="1500"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is the [ES6 Generator `function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2A) along with its `yield` statement.

That allows you to pause a function and restart it later where it has been paused:

```js
N = 100; // Array Size
XYs = 5; // Element Visual Size
Xp = 1; // Start Pos X
Yp = 1; // Start Pos Y
var canvas;
var l = Array.apply(null, {
  length: N
}).map(Number.call, Number);

Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
  var i = this.length,
    j, temp;
  if (i == 0) return this;
  while (--i) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    temp = this[i];
    this[i] = this[j];
    this[j] = temp;
  }
  return this;
}

function map_range(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) {
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}

function rainbow(x) {
  var m = map_range(x, 0, N, 0, 359);
  return 'hsl(' + m + ',100%,50%)';
}

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  l.shuffle();
  var sort = bubbleSort(l);
  // an anim function triggered every 60th of a second
  function anim(){
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
    draw();
    sort.next(); // call next iteration of the bubbleSort function
  }
  anim();
}

function draw() {
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = rainbow(l[i]);
      ctx.fillRect((Xp * i) * XYs, Yp * XYs, XYs, XYs);
    }
  }
}

function* bubbleSort(a) { // * is magic
  var swapped;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
      if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
        var temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i + 1];
        a[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
        yield swapped; // pause here
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);
}
init();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="20">
```

You can also now use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) for a more readable code achieving the same goal:

```js
const N = 100; // Array Size
const XYs = 5; // Element Visual Size
const Xp = 1; // Start Pos X
const Yp = 1; // Start Pos Y
let canvas;
const l = Array.from({ length: N }, (_,i) => i);

Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
  let i = this.length;
  if (i == 0) return this;
  while (--i) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    const temp = this[i];
    this[i] = this[j];
    this[j] = temp;
  }
  return this;
}

function map_range(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) {
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}

function rainbow(x) {
  const m = map_range(x, 0, N, 0, 359);
  return 'hsl(' + m + ',100%,50%)';
}

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  l.shuffle();
  bubbleSort(l);
}

function draw() {
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    for (let i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = rainbow(l[i]);
      ctx.fillRect((Xp * i) * XYs, Yp * XYs, XYs, XYs);
    }
  }
}
function drawNextFrame() {
  return new Promise((res) => requestAnimationFrame(res))
    .then(draw);
}
async function bubbleSort(a) { // async is magic
  let swapped;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
      if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
        const temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i + 1];
        a[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
        await drawNextFrame(); // pause here
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);
}
init();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="20">
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Is there a way to speed up the animation or will requestAnimationFrame limit to 60fps?

Comment: @PeterMcKinney you could call multiple times your function in the anim func. rAF will try to keep a stable rate just before the screen refresh.

Comment: by moving `sort.next()` into a set interval timer outside of the anim function I was able to speed up the sorter while keeping fps at 60! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need a render loop. requestAnimationFrame() is your friend here. With this method you give the browser a callback that is called before the next frame draw.

Within that callback you draw your stuff and call requestAnimationFrame() again with your same callback like this:

```
requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
function renderLoop()
{
    // visualize your array `l` at this point

    // call the render callback for the next frame draw
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

You get a smooth animation with usually a framerate of 60 fps.

For integrating that approach in your code:

1. Delete the lines

   ```
   draw();
   setTimeout(function() {}, 10);
   ```
2. call the initial

   requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);

   when your program start.