# How to allow Web Workers to receive new data while it still performing computation?

Tags: javascript, sorting, interrupt, web-worker, worker

I want to sort an array, using Web Workers. But this array might receive new values over time, while the worker is still performing the sort function.

So my question is, how can I "stop" the sorting computation on the worker after receiving the new item, so it can perform the sort on the array with that item, while still keeping the sorting that was already made?

Example:

```js
let worker = new Worker('worker.js');
let list = [10,1,5,2,14,3];
worker.postMessage({ list });
setInterval(() => worker.postMessage({ num: SOME_RANDOM_NUM, list }), 100);

worker.onmessage = event => {
  list = event.data.list;
}
```

So lets say that, I've passed 50, the worker made some progress in the sorting before that and now I have something like this:
`[1, 2, 3, 10, 5, 14, 50]`. Which means the sorting stopped at index `3`. So I pass this `new` array back to the worker, so it can continue the sorting from position `3`.

How can I accomplish that, since there is no way to pause/resume a web worker?

Comment: Just an idea - you can have a flag in your worker, initially FALSE. When you send the message with the new item - the message handler should set the flag to TRUE. Your sorting function will check the flag on each iteration - and if there is a new item will add it to the list, reset the flag and continue with the sorting.

Comment: _"while still keeping the sorting that was already made?"_ What should occur if the new value should be inserted into the previously sorted data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though the Worker works on an other thread than the one of your main page, and can thus run continuously without blocking the UI, it still runs on a single thread.

This means that until your sort algorithm has finished, the Worker will delay the execution of the message event handler; it is as blocked as would be the main thread.

Even if you made use of an other Worker from inside this worker, the problem would be the same.

The only solution would be to use a kind of [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) as the sorter, and to yield it every now and then so that the events can get executed.

**But doing this will drastically slow down your sorting algorithm.**

To make it better, you could try to hook to each Event Loop, thanks to a MessageChannel object: you talk in one port and receive the message in the next Event loop. If you talk again to the other port, then you have your own hook to each Event loop.

Now, the best would be to run a good batch in every of these Event loop, but for demo, I'll call only one instance of our generator function (that I borrowed from [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46951400/3702797))

```js
const worker = new Worker(getWorkerURL());
worker.onmessage = draw;

onclick = e =>     worker.postMessage(0x0000FF/0xFFFFFF); // add a red pixel

// every frame we request the current state from Worker
function requestFrame() {
  worker.postMessage('gimme a frame');
  requestAnimationFrame(requestFrame);
}
requestFrame();

// drawing part
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const img = ctx.createImageData(50, 50);
const data = new Uint32Array(img.data.buffer);
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

function draw(evt) {
  // converts 0&1 to black and white pixels
  const list = evt.data;
  list.forEach((bool, i) =>
    data[i] = (bool * 0xFFFFFF) + 0xFF000000
  );
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.putImageData(img,0,0);
  // draw bigger
  ctx.scale(5,5);
  ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0,0);
}

function getWorkerURL() {
  const script = document.querySelector('[type="worker-script"]');
  const blob = new Blob([script.textContent]);
  return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}
```

```css
body{
  background: ivory;
}
```

```html
<script type="worker-script">
// our list
const list = Array.from({length: 2500}).map(_=>+(Math.random()>.5));
// our sorter generator
let sorter = bubbleSort(list);
let done = false;
/* inner messaging channel */
const msg_channel = new MessageChannel();
// Hook to every Event loop
msg_channel.port2.onmessage = e => {
  // procede next step in sorting algo
  // could be a few thousands in a loop
  const state = sorter.next();
  // while running
  if(!state.done) {
    msg_channel.port1.postMessage('');
    done = false;
  }
  else {
    done = true;
  }
}
msg_channel.port1.postMessage("");

/* outer messaging channel (from main) */
self.onmessage = e => {
  if(e.data === "gimme a frame") {
    self.postMessage(list);
  }
  else {
    list.push(e.data);
    if(done) { // restart the sorter
      sorter = bubbleSort(list);
      msg_channel.port1.postMessage('');
    }
  }
};

function* bubbleSort(a) { // * is magic
  var swapped;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
      if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
        var temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i + 1];
        a[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
        yield swapped; // pause here
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);
}
</script>
<pre> click to add red pixels</pre>
<canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```

Note that the same can be achieved with an async function, which may be more practical in some cases:

```js
const worker = new Worker(getWorkerURL());
worker.onmessage = draw;

onclick = e =>     worker.postMessage(0x0000FF/0xFFFFFF); // add a red pixel

// every frame we request the current state from Worker
function requestFrame() {
  worker.postMessage('gimme a frame');
  requestAnimationFrame(requestFrame);
}
requestFrame();

// drawing part
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const img = ctx.createImageData(50, 50);
const data = new Uint32Array(img.data.buffer);
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

function draw(evt) {
  // converts 0&1 to black and white pixels
  const list = evt.data;
  list.forEach((bool, i) =>
    data[i] = (bool * 0xFFFFFF) + 0xFF000000
  );
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.putImageData(img,0,0);
  // draw bigger
  ctx.scale(5,5);
  ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0,0);
}

function getWorkerURL() {
  const script = document.querySelector('[type="worker-script"]');
  const blob = new Blob([script.textContent]);
  return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}
```

```css
body{
  background: ivory;
}
```

```html
<script type="worker-script">
// our list
const list = Array.from({length: 2500}).map(_=>+(Math.random()>.5));
// our sorter generator
let done = false;


/* outer messaging channel (from main) */
self.onmessage = e => {
  if(e.data === "gimme a frame") {
    self.postMessage(list);
  }
  else {
    list.push(e.data);
    if(done) { // restart the sorter
      bubbleSort(list);
    }
  }
};

async function bubbleSort(a) { // async is magic
  var swapped;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
      if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
        const temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i + 1];
        a[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
      }
      if( i % 50 === 0 ) { // by batches of 50?
        await waitNextTask(); // pause here
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);
  done = true;
}

function waitNextTask() {
  return new Promise( (resolve) => {
    const channel = waitNextTask.channel ||= new MessageChannel();
    channel.port1.addEventListener("message", (evt) => resolve(), { once: true });
    channel.port2.postMessage("");
    channel.port1.start();
  });
}

bubbleSort(list);
</script>
<pre> click to add red pixels</pre>
<canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two decent options.

### Option 1: `Worker.terminate()`

The first is just to kill your existing web worker and start a new one. For that you can use [`Worker.terminate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/terminate).

> The `terminate()` method of the `Worker` interface immediately terminates the `Worker`. This does not offer the worker an opportunity to finish its operations; it is simply stopped at once.

The only downsides of this approach are:

- You lose all worker state. If you had to copy a load of data into it for the request you have to do it all again.
- It involves thread creation and destruction, which isn't as slow as most people think but if you terminate web workers a *lot* it might cause issues.

If neither of those are an issue it is probably the easiest option.

In my case I have lots of state. My worker is rendering part of an image, and when the user pans to a different area I want it to stop what it is doing and start rendering the new area. But the data needed to render the image is pretty huge.

In your case you have the state of your (presumably huge) list that you don't want to use.

### Option 2: Yielding

The second option is basically to do cooperative multitasking. You run your computation as normal, but every now and then you pause (yield) and say "should I stop?", like this (this is for some nonsense calculation, not sorting).

```
let requestId = 0;

onmessage = event => {
  ++requestId;
  sortAndSendData(requestId, event.data);
}

function sortAndSendData(thisRequestId, data) {
  let isSorted = false;
  let total = 0;

  while (data !== 0) {
    // Do a little bit of computation.
    total += data;
    --data;

    // Check if we are still the current request ID.
    if (thisRequestId !== requestId) {
      // Data was changed. Cancel this sort.
      return;
    }
  }

  postMessage(total);
}
```

This won't work though because `sortAndSendData()` runs to completion and blocks the web worker's event loop. We need some way to yield just before `thisRequestId !== requestId`. Unfortunately Javascript doesn't quite have a `yield` method. It does have `async`/`await` so we might try this:

```
let requestId = 0;

onmessage = event => {
  console.log("Got event", event);
  ++requestId;
  sortAndSendData(requestId, event.data);
}

async function sortAndSendData(thisRequestId, data) {
  let isSorted = false;
  let total = 0;

  while (data !== 0) {
    // Do a little bit of computation.
    total += data;
    --data;

    await Promise.resolve();

    // Check if we are still the current request ID.
    if (thisRequestId !== requestId) {
      console.log("Cancelled!");
      // Data was changed. Cancel this sort.
      return;
    }
  }

  postMessage(total);
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I think it's because `async`/`await` executes things eagerly using "microtasks", which get executed before pending "macrotasks" (our web worker message) if possible.

We need to force our `await` to become a macrotask, which you can do using `setTimeout(0)`:

```
let requestId = 0;

onmessage = event => {
  console.log("Got event", event);
  ++requestId;
  sortAndSendData(requestId, event.data);
}

function yieldToMacrotasks() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve));
}

async function sortAndSendData(thisRequestId, data) {
  let isSorted = false;
  let total = 0;

  while (data !== 0) {
    // Do a little bit of computation.
    total += data;
    --data;

    await yieldToMacrotasks();

    // Check if we are still the current request ID.
    if (thisRequestId !== requestId) {
      console.log("Cancelled!");
      // Data was changed. Cancel this sort.
      return;
    }
  }

  postMessage(total);
}
```

This works! However it is extremely slow. `await yieldToMacrotasks()` takes approximately 4 ms on my machine with Chrome! This is because browsers set a minimum timeout on `setTimeout(0)` of something like 1 or 4 ms (the actual minimum seems to be complicated).

Fortunately another user pointed me to [a quicker way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61339321/265521). Basically sending a message on another `MessageChannel` also yields to the event loop, but isn't subject to the minimum delay like `setTimeout(0)` is. This code works and each loop only takes ~0.04 ms which should be fine.

```
let currentTask = {
  cancelled: false,
}

onmessage = event => {
  currentTask.cancelled = true;
  currentTask = {
    cancelled: false,
  };
  performComputation(currentTask, event.data);
}

async function performComputation(task, data) {
  let total = 0;

  let promiseResolver;

  const channel = new MessageChannel();
  channel.port2.onmessage = event => {
    promiseResolver();
  };

  while (data !== 0) {
    // Do a little bit of computation.
    total += data;
    --data;

    // Yield to the event loop.
    const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
      promiseResolver = resolve;
    });
    channel.port1.postMessage(null);
    await promise;

    // Check if this task has been superceded by another one.
    if (task.cancelled) {
      return;
    }
  }

  // Return the result.
  postMessage(total);
}
```

I'm not totally happy about it - it relies on `postMessage()` events being processed in FIFO order, which I doubt is guaranteed. I suspect you could rewrite the code to make it work even if that isn't true.

Comment: i would be pretty worried if postMessage events were *not* a FIFO

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with some trick – with the help of `setTimeout` function interrupting. For example it is not possible without an addition thread to execute 2 functions parallel, but with `setTimeout` function interrupting trick we can do it like follows:

**Example of parallel execution of functions**

```js
var count_0 = 0,
    count_1 = 0;

function func_0()
{
    if(count_0 < 3)
        setTimeout(func_0, 0);//the same: setTimeout(func_0);

    console.log('count_0 = '+count_0);
    count_0++
}

function func_1()
{
    if(count_1 < 3)
        setTimeout(func_1, 0);

    console.log('count_1 = '+count_1)
    count_1++
}

func_0();
func_1();
```

You will get this output:

> count_0 = 0
> count_1 = 0
> count_0 = 1
> count_1 = 1
> count_0 = 2
> count_1 = 2
> count_0 = 3
> count_1 = 3

Why is it possible? Because the `setTimeout` function needs some time to be executed. And this time is even enought for the execution of some part from your following code.

**Solution for you**

For this case you have to write your own array sort function (or you can also use the following function from me) because we can not interrupt the native `sort` function. And in this your own function you have to use this `setTimeout` function interrupting trick. And you can receive your `message` event notification.

In the following example I have the interrupting in the half length of my array, and you can change it if you want.

**Example with custom sort function interrupting**

```js
var numbers = [4, 2, 1, 3, 5];

// this is my bubble sort function with interruption
/**
 * Sorting an array. You will get the same, but sorted array.
 * @param {array[]} arr – array to sort
 * @param {number} dir – if dir = -1 you will get an array like [5,4,3,2,1]
 *                 and if dir = 1 in opposite direction like [1,2,3,4,5]
 * @param {number} passCount – it is used only for setTimeout interrupting trick.
 */
function sortNumbersWithInterruption(arr, dir, passCount)
{
    var passes = passCount || arr.length,
        halfOfArrayLength = (arr.length / 2) | 0; // for ex. 2.5 | 0 = 2

    // Why we need while loop: some values are on
    // the end of array and we have to change their
    // positions until they move to the first place of array.
    while(passes--)
    {
        if(!passCount && passes == halfOfArrayLength)
        {
            // if you want you can also not write the following line for full break of sorting
            setTimeout(function(){sortNumbersWithInterruption(arr, dir, passes)}, 0);
            /*
                You can do here all what you want. Place 1
            */
            break
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
        {
            var a = arr[i],
                b = arr[i+1];

            if((a - b) * dir > 0)
            {
                arr[i] = b;
                arr[i+1] = a;
            }
        }

        console.log('array is: ' + arr.join());
    }

    if(passCount)
        console.log('END sring is: ' + arr.join());
}

sortNumbersWithInterruption(numbers, -1); //without passCount parameter
/*
    You can do here all what you want. Place 2
*/
console.log('The execution is here now!');
```

You will get this output:

> array is: 4,2,3,5,1
> array is: 4,3,5,2,1
> The execution is here now!
> array is: 4,5,3,2,1
> array is: 5,4,3,2,1
> END sring is: 5,4,3,2,1

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more. Ie: how would I pass a new number (from the outside) to `sortNumbersWithInterruption`?

Comment: @KadoBOT, if you want to add a new number to this array and if you want that this new lalue will be sorted too, then you have to break the while loop without `setTimeout` and start the sorting new because a part of numbers was already sorted / moved. A new value to your array you can add with `push` function of array.

Comment: Thats the part where I'm struggling :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with insertion sort (kind of).
Here is the idea:

1. Start your worker with an internal empty array (empty array is sorted obviously)
2. Your worker receives only elements not the entire array
3. Your worker insert any received element right in correct position into the array
4. Every n seconds, the worker raises a message with the current array if it has changed after the last event. (If you prefer, you can send the array on every insertion, but is more efficient to buffer somehow)

Eventually, you get the entire array, if any item is added, you will receive the updated array to.

NOTE: Because your array is always sorted, you can insert in correct position using binary search. This is very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think the case comes down to careful management of `postMessage` calls and amount of data passed to be processed at a time. Was dealing with problem of this kind - think about not sending all new data into the function at once but rather creating your own queue and when small enough portion of the task has been acomplished by `webworker` thread send a message back to the main thread and decide to send the next portion, wait or quit.

In Your case, e.g. one time You get 9000 new items, next 100k - maybe create a queue/buffer that adds next 10k new elements each time webworker is done processing last data change.

```
const someWorker = new Worker('abc.js');

var processingLock = false;
var queue = [];

function newDataAction(arr = null) {

    if (arr != null) {
        queue = queue.concat(arr);
    }

    if (!processingLock) {
        processingLock = true;
        var data = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 10000 && queue.length > 0; i++) {
            data.push(queue.pop());
        }

        worker.postMessage(data);
    }
}

someWorker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    if (e.data == 'finished-last-task') {
       processingLock = false;
       if (queue.length > 0) {
           newDataAction();
       }
    }
});
```

Worked through many sorting algorithms and I don't see how sending new data into an sorting algorithm with partially sorted array makes much difference in terms of compuation time from sorting them both sequentially and performing a merge.